# Msg 242: conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have gone through a bunch of posts here with this error and tried changing data types and used Convert but nothing seems to fix this. So I would like to ask for some help here. I will try to give as much info, but feel free to ask if its not enough.

This is where I am getting the error:

```
Insert into prompt(ID, Date)  
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by b.IDLoc),
        [dbo].[fn_GetGPtime](cast (replace(DateCollected, '/', '-') + ' ' + a.UTCTime as datetime))
    from 
        Img a 
    inner join 
        Tloc b on a.Filename = b.filename
    order by 
        b.IDLoc
```

The `Date` column in prompt table has a datatype of `float`. `UTCTime` and `DateCollected` are both `varchar(20)`

The error is:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 274
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Here is the function:

```
[dbo].[fn_GetGPtime] (@UTCtime datetime)
returns varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    return (DATEPART (WEEKDAY, @UTCtime) - 1) * 86400 ---day
            + DATEPART (HOUR, @UTCtime) * 3600 ---hour
            + DATEPART (MINUTE, @UTCtime) * 60 ----minutes
            + DATEPART (SECOND, @UTCtime) ---second
            + (DATEPART (MILLISECOND, @UTCtime)) * 0.001 ---ms
            + (DATEPART (MICROSECOND, @UTCtime)) * 0.000001 ---us
            + 16 ----leap seconds
end;
```

To get an idea of the data itself:

[image]

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: What's the `MIN()` date collected?  Any blank or `NULL` dates?

Comment: @AaronDeitz Min value of datecollected is 07/17/2017. No Null dates or ''

Comment: @marc_s I agree with you and Rominus on good decisions about datattypes but unfortunately sometime you inherit stuff that is not ideal. I can not make the changes to the datatypes because it has a front end integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message could mean two different things: that you have non-convertible data in some cells, or that field's data are not convertible to datetime at all.

You can use `try_convert` instead of `convert` to figure out which it is.  It will solve your problem if you have a few completely unusable values (i.e. bad data); you'll get nulls for bad data and good conversion for good data.  If the overall conversion is never going to work you'll get all nulls and you'll know it isn't just a few bad values.

Another thing you could try is converting from float to numeric before converting to datetime.  I find that float formatted data are awful for conversions and converting to numeric can remove many issues.  You'd have something like `convert(datetime, convert(numeric(18,2), UTCTime))`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) instead of `cast`. When using `convert`, you can specify the format of the string representing the date.
Once you've converted `DateCollected` to `datetime`, you can cast `a.UTCTime` to `datetime` and add them together:

```
Insert into prompt(ID,Date)  
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by b.IDLoc),
[dbo].[fn_GetGPtime](convert(datetime, DateCollected, 101) + cast(a.UTCTime as datetime))
from Img a inner join Tloc b on a.Filename=b.filename
order by b.IDLoc
```

(assuming `a.UTCTime` is either `varchar` or `time`)

Comment: @ZoherPaled UTCTime and DateCollected are both varchar(20). I tried your recommended query but getting the same error.

Comment: what version of sql server are you working with? Also, try to run `select convert(datetime, DateCollected, 101) from Img` and see what you get.

Comment: Sql Server version is 2014 and I tried this and it ran giving results like 2017-07-19 00:00:00.000

Comment: Running the same for Time like select convert(datetime, UTCTime, 101) from Img is giving the error

Comment: This means that at least one value in the UTCTime column has data that can't be converted datetime. You can use try_convert but note it will return null for data that can't be converted.

Comment: @ZohairPeled I tried this   (SELECT   
    CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(datetime,   '12:59:60.00') IS NULL   
    THEN 'Cast failed'  
    ELSE 'Cast succeeded'  
 
END AS Result). This is the only one that failed. Any idea why this value?

Comment: Yes. there is no second 60. it should be 13:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, solving this error on an input line such as

```
SELECT CAST(N'2003-12-01 14:20:47.000' AS DateTime) AS result
```

Msg 242 Level 16 ...

is the magic instruction:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
```